# Setting the font size when creating a table

Tags: itext

I have successfully created a table within a .pdf document using ITextSharp using data from a Excel document. I have set the columns width of the .pdf table so it is the same as the Excel document.

However when  I view the .pdf document the layout doesn't match that of the Excel document.

I think the problem is with the font style/size being used when the table is being created.
I have searched online for how to change the default font style/size of a table being created in a .pdf, but I'm not totally clear on how it's done (I've never worked with fonts).

Here's what I have so.

```
private void WritePDFTable(ExcelWorksheet sheet, Document doc)
    {
        var start = sheet.Dimension.Start;
        var end = sheet.Dimension.End;

        float[] ColumnWidths = new float[end.Column];
        float TotalWidth = 0f;
        int row;
        int column;

        if (sheet.Dimension != null)    // make sure the sheet isn't empty
        {
            if (end.Column > 0) // create a table to hold the columns in the passed worksheet
            {
                for (column = start.Column; column <= end.Column; column++)
                {
                    ColumnWidths[column - 1] = (float)(sheet.Column(column).Width);
                    TotalWidth = TotalWidth + (float)(sheet.Column(column).Width);
                }

                    // creat a pdf table with  the same # of columns as were found in the workbook
                    PdfPTable PdfPTable = new PdfPTable(end.Column);

                    // set absolute width of the columns
                PdfPTable.SetWidths(ColumnWidths);  

                PdfPTable.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                PdfPTable.SpacingAfter = 30f;


                for (row = start.Row; row <= end.Row;row++)                    {
                    for (column = start.Column; column <= end.Column; column++)                         {
                        PdfPTable.AddCell(sheet.Cells[row, column].Text);
                    }
                }
                doc.Add(PdfPTable);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a `Font font` with the desired `fontSize` value, e.g. like this

```
Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, fontSize);
```

or this

```
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", fontSize, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

(use the iTextSharp `Font` class, not a Windows API `Font` class), simply replace

```
PdfPTable.AddCell(sheet.Cells[row, column].Text);
```

by

```
PdfPTable.AddCell(new Phrase(sheet.Cells[row, column].Text, font));
```

to get cells with text of the desired size.